# Is there only one method? for miner and pool communication?

Tags: mining-pools

I tried doing some sort of filtering on XMRig using wireshark on an ETN pool[image: here!] and I found that XMRig was using `login` method of JSON-RPC 2.0, my question is does all miners use this method? By "all" I mean even the bitcoin, monero and all minable cryptocurrency miners use this method? I heard about GBT, stratum and getwork, are they just a simple "sub-part" of JSON-RPC?

Answer (score 1):

JSON-RPC as a protocol does not specify other protocols that use it. Rather it just defines the general structure that protocols using JSON-RPC should use. JSON-RPC does not define any methods; `login` is a method that is offered by protocols using JSON-RPC.

GBT, stratum, and getwork use JSON-RPC. They themselves are not JSON-RPC or some subset of JSON-RPC. Furthermore, none of those have a `login` method.

There is no guarantee that all coins use the same protocol (GBT, stratum, or getwork) nor that they use JSON-RPC. Typically coins will use one of those or something similar because they simply copy existing code, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: I am sorry I have not enough reputation for commenting, but from the answer of Andrew Chow above, thank you that was very informative, so what you mean is that the protocols uses differs from either the coin or the pool?

Comment: Yes, the use of pool protocol depends entirely on the pool. The coin doesn't actually matter that much (besides that the data transmitted depends on the coin). It's really up to the pool.